# convert csv to a string variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am  a beginner in python. I    need help with   the following

I have a   comma separated csv file, eg

```
a,b,c
d,e,f
g,h,i
```

I  need  to convert   to a string variable eg
    s='a,b,c\n,d,e,f\n,g,h,i\n'

I  tried something, but i am going wrong somewhere.

```
import os
import csv
Filename=r"c:\Users\das\Desktop\a.csv"
z=open(Filename, 'r')
reader=csv.reader(Filename.split('\n'),delimiter=',')
def csv2str():
    for row  in reader:
        v=','.join(row)

a=csv2str()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need the csv module to do that. Just call the `read` method of the file object to *read* in all the lines as one string:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    s = f.read() + '\n' # add trailing new line character

print(repr(s))
# 'a,b,c\nd,e,f\ng,h,i\n'
```

I'm printing the `repr` of the string because a print of the string itself i.e. `print(a)` will not show the newline character as `\n`, but will show the string in its different lines.

Comment: Thanks, was looking for that !!